# Solr Sunspot non-indexed field

Tags: lucene, solr, sunspot, sunspot-rails

Solr (via Lucene) supports different ways to indicate the way a field is indexed in a document: indexed, tokenized, stored,...

I'm looking for a way to have fields that are stored in Solr but are not indexed. Is there a way to achieve that in Sunspot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sunspot's configuration DSL supports an option of `:stored => true` for many of its default types. For the example of the stored string, it would be much simpler than my first example:

```
searchable do
  string :name, :stored => true
end
```

This generates a field name of `name_ss` corresponding to the following `dynamicField` already present in Sunspot's standard schema:

```
<dynamicField name="*_ss" stored="true" type="string" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
```

You can also create your own custom `field` or `dynamicField` in your schema.xml to be stored but not indexed, and then use the Sunspot 1.2 `:as` option to specify a corresponding field name.

For example, a more verbose version of the above. In your schema:

```
<dynamicField name="*_stored_string" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true" />
```

And in your model:

```
searchable do
  string :name, :as => 'name_stored_string'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/luke?numTerms=0

And read with xpath or regex those fields with schema attribute value:

```
<str name="I">Indexed</str>
<str name="T">Tokenized</str>
<str name="S">Stored</str>
```

You will get something like:

```
<lst name="field">
<str name="type">stringGeneralType</str>
<str name="schema">--SM---------</str>
</lst>
```

Comment: That will tell me if a field is stored/indexed or not. But is not a way to tell Solr about the field storage attributes. Or am I missing something here?